# How do I allow only one checkbox to be selected out of a group of checkboxes?

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

I have two groups of checkboxes.

**Group 1**

```
CheckboxA
CheckboxB
```

**Group 2**

```
CheckboxC
CheckboxD
CheckboxE
```

How do I allow only one of the checkboxes to be selected from each group? Also is there a way to link the outcome data from a group of checkboxes?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

With ActiveSheet
    Select Case Range("H5").Value

    Case "London"
        .Shapes("CheckboxB").Visible = True
        .Shapes("CheckboxA").Visible = False

    Case "England/Wales"
        .Shapes("CheckboxA").Visible = False
        .Shapes("CheckboxB").Visible = True

    Case "Scotland"
        .Shapes("CheckboxB").Visible = False
        .Shapes("CheckboxA").Visible = True

    Case ""
        .Shapes("CheckboxA").Visible = False
        .Shapes("CheckboxB").Visible = False

    End Select

    Select Case Range("H6").Value

    Case "Pay Later"
        .Shapes("CheckboxC").Visible = True
        .Shapes("CheckboxD").Visible = True
        .Shapes("CheckboxE").Visible = True

    Case "Pay Now"
        .Shapes("CheckboxC").Visible = True
        .Shapes("CheckboxD").Visible = True
        .Shapes("CheckboxE").Visible = True

    Case "Core NSNF"
        .Shapes("CheckboxC").Visible = True
        .Shapes("CheckboxD").Visible = False
        .Shapes("CheckboxE").Visible = False

    Case "Premium NSNF"
        .Shapes("CheckboxC").Visible = False
        .Shapes("CheckboxD").Visible = False
        .Shapes("CheckboxE").Visible = False

    Case ""
        .Shapes("CheckboxC").Visible = False
        .Shapes("CheckboxD").Visible = False
        .Shapes("CheckboxE").Visible = False

    End Select

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: If you only want a single option to be selected from a group of options, the best ways to do that are a drop-down list (combobox control) or a group of OptionButtons.  You can set OptionButtons to a group so that only a single selection can be made from that group.

Comment: Are you able to show/hide option buttons based on a cell value?

Comment: Yes, using basically the same code you already have.

Comment: I can't seem to get it working

Comment: `.Shapes("Option Button 1").Visible = True` adjust the option button name to match your actual option button name, verified that this works for both Form controls and ActiveX controls.

Comment: Have I gone wrong anywhere? Still doesn't seem to be working:


`Sub OptionButtonABC_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

With ActiveSheet

    Select Case Range("A1").Value

    Case "Y"
        .Shapes("OptionButtonABC").Visible = True
        
    Case "N"
        .Shapes("OptionButtonABC").Visible = False
        
    End Select

End With

End`

Comment: The worksheet_change event you provided in your previous comment works for me successfully with no issues.  I just had to make sure I had an option button named `OptionButtonABC`.

Comment: This is how I'm creating an Option Button:

`Sub Macrol()
ActiveSheet.OptionButton.Add(171, 18, 72, 65.26).Selct
Selection.Name = "OptionButtonA"
End Sub`